# How to Automate action in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel sheet , both contain name of items but in mix manner,

for example in one sheet apple is the first item while in other, apple is 9th item
I need to copy the item from the first sheet and find if it exists in the second sheet ,if it exist then copy the cost of it from the first sheet, add 100 to it then paste it on the second sheet, need to do it recursively for 10000 times 
what is the best approach to automate this problem

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. Unfortunately, your question is considered off-topic here on SuperUser. We can tell you a good approach on how to do it manually, but even then, its a matter of opinion. Automating this means writing a script, but we're not a "script writing service". If you have a script, we can help you finding out why its not working. Please see the help center to see what kind of question is allowed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with two formulas.

On your third sheet, column A should contain:

> =VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$6,1,FALSE)

with $A$1:$B$6 substituted for the range of data.

next, Column B should contain:

> =SUM(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$6,2,FALSE)*100)

The first formula checks to see if the first item in column A on sheet 2 is in column A of sheet 1.

the second formula returns the value listed for the item from sheet 1, and multiplys by 100.

This should just dragcopy and work, but it will return n/a for an item on sheet 2 not on sheet 1.